# Сколько памяти необходимо выделить под Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ос

Хочу поставить Ubuntu себе на компьютер рядом с Windows 7, дошёл до этапа с разделением места на диске (выбрал пункт установить рядом с Windows)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На самом диске, куда автоматически предложило сохранить Ubuntu, имеется 1ТБ памяти, может этот вопрос немного глупый, но сколько необходимо выделить под Ubuntu. Я так понимаю эта память будет выделена именна для этой ОС, для личных же файлов будет задействоваться оставшаяся память на этом диске?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Под саму Ubuntu вполне хватит 100гигабайт (это если на поиграться). А оставшееся место - это место, которое будет оставлено для Windows. Но смотрите аккуратно и не удалите его (если он конечно Вам нужен).

То есть, на приведенном скриншоте, установщик спрашивает, сколько места оставить для Windows, а сколько под Ubuntu.

Имейте ввиду, что раздел диска с Windows как минимум будет доступен для чтения с под Ubuntu, но не наоборот.

Личные файлы, который Вы будете использовать в Ubuntu, лучше хранить в свободном месте на разделе с Ubuntu. Поэтому, если Вы собираетесь монтировать видео, то лучше взять с запасом, побольше. Если же просто смотреть интернет, то 100 Гб будет достаточно (но я бы взял 200).

**update**

Специально нашел [минимальные требования](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) - диск 25 Гигабайт. Но это все таки минимальные. Там же пишут, что можно и на 8 заставить работать, но уже с области спортивной установки.

Comment: Дело в том, что в диске который установщик выбрал автоматически, нет Windows, он у меня ранее стоял на другом диске, на этом же диске у меня располагались мои файлы. Что произойдет после того как я выделю по Ubuntu скажем 200ГБ, остальной памятью я смогу пользоваться на Ubuntu?

Comment: да, скорее всего Вы сможете ими пользоваться на чтение. А вот на запись - тут сложнее. В целом Ubuntu поддерживает ntfs, но современные windows любят впадать в hibernate и оставлять файловую систему в "подвешенном состоянии". А убунта, как культурная ОС не будет туда писать

Comment: Понял, огромное спасибо!

Comment: @KoVadim, я бы добавил про разделение `/` и `/home` в ответ, потому что пропустить такую искоробочную киллерфичу - ну прям ваще не айс.

Comment: Могу сказать про свой опыт. Для корня вполне хватает 50 ГБ, для `/home` в принципе тоже 50. Кинцо и мемы лучше хранить на "D:\" в `ntfs`.

Comment: посмотрел на домашний сервачек. там 128 ссд (система) + 2тб hdd (файлопомойка). Занято 52 гигабайта на ссд. 50 хватит, пока не захочется побаловаться docker или какой то нибудь npm запустить

Comment: @KoVadim, `/var/cache/docker` вполне можно или симлинкнуть или маунт-биндить на 2тб или nfs. Тут только в скорость i/o упирается. У меня на работе система на винте, а наиболее востребованные виртуалки виртуалбокса на ссд (на нём кроме виртуалок вообще ничего нет). Всё работает оч шустро, т.к. комп выключается только по воле электриков.

Answer (score 1):

Моя система: `/` на отдельном диске 100G  , из них `swap` 4096M в начале диска.  `/home`на другом диске 500G. Для кино музыки и т. д . отдельный  диск на  1Т с файловой системой  `btrfs`. Эта конфигурация работает уже лет 5, и горя не знаю...